# Firebase local emulator suite | how to disable cache

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

On retrieving a doc from Firestore and manually deleting it on the Firebase Emulator console. The data doesnt get deleted on the client side..

I have to manually clear data site with chrome dev tools
[image]

I tried disabling cache from chrome but that **doesn't work**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular..

On your `app.module.ts`

Remove `enableIndexedDbPersistence(firestore)`

```
provideFirestore(() => {
  if (environment.useEmulators) {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
    // enableIndexedDbPersistence(firestore);  <=============== Remove this line
    return firestore;
  } else return getFirestore();
}),
```